# Proper usage of tf.reset_default_graph() to destruct a graph

Tags: tensorflow

Looking at the definition of [tf.reset_default_graph()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reset_default_graph), it seems to me that `tf.reset_default_graph()` does not reset the value of a tensor (e.g., weights) inside a graph when I use `tf.Session()` in a loop:

```
import tensorflow as tf

for i in range(X):
  #import a pretrained graph
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(META)
    saver.restore(sess,MODEL)
    sess.run(TENSORS_IN_PRETRAINED_MDOEL)
    print sess.run(...)
    #Do sth with weghts X times here
    sess.run(tf.assign([v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if v.name == OLD_VALUE ][0], NEW_VALUE))
  tf.reset_default_graph()
```

How can I completely destruct the tf.graph on a nested loop?

P.s: I did try `new_graph()` as well without success.

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: Thanks @Maxim for pointing this out. see my updated question

Comment: I get zeros due to initializer. Is this what you expect? Where is the problem?

Comment: @Maxim, that was just my high-level example. After I use the `save.restore()`, I can run the tensor directly. I updated the question again.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You mention the weights not being reset but the weights (values of variables, not constants) only exist within a session. There is no need to reset them if you close the session as you do (using a `with` statement). But it also doesn't seem to be a typical usecase to want to do that in a loop. It will be quite slow to restore the session every time.

Comment: @de1 It is indeed and unfortunately, I did not find any better way to keep the meta-graph and just reload the weights. You got any suggestions on this usecase?

Comment: @Amir you can import the meta graph outside the session (which can also be scoped within a graph). `save.restore` will restore the weights. But why do you want to restore the weights every time?

Comment: @de1 because I am changing them every time

Answer (score 0):

@de1 's comment was right. I think that you confound the session and the graph.

1. When you draw operations like `tf.add`, `tf.matmul`, `tf.nn.conv2d` in the graph, you only put nodes in the graph.
2. When you do `tf.reset_default_graph()` you clean these nodes in the default graph. You can draw several graphs by `graph1 = tf.Graph()` `graph2 = tf.Graph()`. You can choose which graph to launch session by doing `with graph2.as_default()`
3. Variables like weights and bias only exist in session. That's why you always do `tf.global_variables_initializer()` inside a session.

**To answer your question:**
You can try:

```
for i in range(X):
     graphX = tf.Graph() # every time you overwrite it
     with graphX.as_default():
          with tf.Session(graph=graphX) as sess: #make sure which graph use
               ...
```

Hope that it helps